# How can I add a video to my website that plays when you click a button?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am trying to create a game where you enter a number between 1-50 into a textbox, then you click `"Lock In"` to hold your answer so you can't cheat.

Then you press `"Random Number"` and it gives you a number between 1-50. But before it gives you the number I want it to play a clip I made of numbers scrolling through (Kind of like a slot machine). The problem is that for some reason I cant get the clip to play when you press the button.

Here is the code I have:

```
<video id="wheelspin" width="320" height="176">
  <source src="video/SpinWheelAnimation.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<script>
  var vid = document.getElementById("wheelspin");

  function playVideo() {
    vid.play();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Are there any messages/errors/warnings in the developer tools console when you click the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<video id="wheelspin" width="320" height="176">
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<button id="playBtn">Play</button>
<script>
    // Keep the DOM clean with an IIFE 
    // or use a single object (var window.yourname = window.yourname || {};) 
    // or use BabelJS with ES6+
    (function(){
        // Get all the DOM elements
        var vid = document.getElementById("wheelspin");         
        var btn = document.getElementById('playBtn'); 
        // Or use one of the other methods to get the button
        //var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
        //var btn = document.querySelector('button');    

        // Register event handlers with addEventListener(event, callback)
        // Structure (HTML5), Presentation (CSS3) & Behaviour (EcmaScript aka JavaScript)
        var evt = 'ontouchstart' in window ? 'touchstart' : 'click';
        btn.addEventListener(evt, function(){ 
            vid.play();
        });
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing to Stack Overflow! In future, consider providing some explanation and/or inline documentation in code samples to better compliment your answer for added value

Comment: I've made an edit and earned the Editor badge and after posting this comment only 9 more and I'm a Commentator. Can't vote on my own post? This answer is very useful.  Haha.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. You just need to attach the button's onClick event to the playVideo() function.

```html
<video id="wheelspin" width="320" height="176">
                    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
                <button onClick="playVideo()">Play</button>
<script>
    var vid = document.getElementById("wheelspin");

    function playVideo() {
        vid.play();
    }
</script>
```